# Issue with the NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I've been trying to get an OpenAL port for Android 2.2 working via the NDK, but I get an error along the way that I can't seem to solve on my own. I've declared several native methods in my Java class:

```
/**
 * Creates a native OpenAL Audio player.
 * @return An int value according to if the action was a success or not.
 */
private native int initALPlayer();
/**
 * Writes raw PCM data to the OpenAL Audio player.
 * @param data
 * @return An int value according to if the action was a success or not.
 */
private native int writeAudio(byte[] data);
/**
 * Closes the native OpenAL Audio player.
 * @return An int value according to if the action was a success or not.
 */
private native int closeALPlayer();
```

I load the correct libraries via System.loadLibrary():

```
static{
    System.loadLibrary("openal");
    System.loadLibrary("audio");
}
```

After this, I created the header file with the javah command

```
javah -classpath bin -d jni org.rohill.privatemobileradio.utilities.AudioProcessor
```

The header file:

```
/*
 * Class:     org_rohill_privatemobileradio_utilities_AudioProcessor
 * Method:    initALPlayer
 * Signature: ()I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_org_rohill_privatemobileradio_utilities_AudioProcessor_initALPlayer
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

/*
 * Class:     org_rohill_privatemobileradio_utilities_AudioProcessor
 * Method:    writeAudio
 * Signature: ([B)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_org_rohill_privatemobileradio_utilities_AudioProcessor_writeAudio
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jbyteArray);

/*
 * Class:     org_rohill_privatemobileradio_utilities_AudioProcessor
 * Method:    closeALPlayer
 * Signature: ()I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_org_rohill_privatemobileradio_utilities_AudioProcessor_closeALPlayer
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);
```

I use this created header file in a C file.

My C implementation:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_org_rohill_privatemobileradio_utilities_AudioProcessor_initALPlayer(JNIEnv * env, jobject object)
{
    return 42;
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_org_rohill_privatemobileradio_utilities_AudioProcessor_writeAudio(JNIEnv * env, jobject object, jbyteArray byteData)
{
    return 43;
}

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_org_rohill_privatemobileradio_utilities_AudioProcessor_closeALPlayer(JNIEnv * env, jobject object)
{
    return 44;
}
```

When I build the library next, all goes well.
But it goes wrong when I try to call a native method:

```
if(initALPlayer() == 1){
    Log.i(TAG, "AL Audio Player initialized");
} else {
    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to initialize AL Audio Player");
}
```

Whenever I try to run this method, I get an error in my logs saying:

```
04-27 08:03:11.072: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(25017): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: initALPlayer
```

However, I have not been able to track down where this goes wrong. I've used the method name declarations from the header file javah created for me. I've checked for typo's but there don't seem to be any...

What really boggles me is that when I use a simpler and easier method, which only returns a string, it works...

If anybody has an idea on how to solve this... please feel free to elaborate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it was some naming convention error with the name of my C file. When I changed that to a simple, one word descriptor of what the file is supposed to do (no special tokens like _ or so), it works... >.< Sigh...

Comment: Facing a similar problem! did not understand what u did? change the filename in NDK to without special characters?

Comment: I've actually written a small document (2 pages, MS Word) about the issue. See [this document](https://www.dropbox.com/s/prv3889szmsl5ee/StepByStep%20Native%20Code.docx) if you're interested.

Comment: The document does not explain it. It is an intro to NDK.

Comment: Although that is true, I wrote it as a result of this issue. Following those steps, I was able to get a working native method. The issue was one of my first attempts to use the NDK. Since I don't know what your situation is, I thought it might be of some help to you.

Comment: I have used NDK for a while now :) my issue is that I have 2 functions with JNIEXPORT, and when I call the second one, I get UnsatisfiedLinkError.

Comment: Then you have some inconsistency with the naming of the second function. It will compile, as you might have noticed, but the Dalvik JVM can't find the function you called natively in your library.

Comment: exactly, so how did u get around this one?

Comment: I checked my method names, class names and namespace names for special characters like spaces or underscores. Those don't translate well when used with the NDK. Hence my mention of the issue being a naming convention.

Answer (score -1):

Java_org_rohill_privatemobileradio_utilities this looks like your project isn't named  
OpenAL or audio.  
 
ndk-build will build and install usually a library called  
lib[yourProjectName]JNI.so  
and  package it with your application.  
You can verify such things by opening the folder libs, 
it does contain a subfolder named "armeabi" (when building for android-arme-abi), 
in which the generated so - file resides. 
So to invoke a native method, this library must be loaded, and your naming conventions 
from the generated header - file should work fine.

Comment: You might notice that they asker of the question stated what their issue was *several years ago*.  Also the **java** package name embedded in the function names has *absolutely nothing* to do with the name of the JNI library containing them.

Comment: Yes, but the library which has to be loaded via System.load obviously does!

Comment: And because people are looking for answers here related to NKD, someone could find this information useful.

Comment: Additionally, you are wrong about the naming pattern.

Comment: It is the project name lib[projectName].so by default. And if this doesn't make sense (as you wrote before), why are you commenting on posts to a question which as started several years ago?

Comment: You've now made two conflicting statements of the file name.  One might ask why you are giving poorly stated answers to an old question, but be aware that when you do, it moves to the top of the display list.

Comment: Oh, Chris I am so afraid of you .. after all you are the holy good of Android NKD, right?

Comment: I always give my .so files specific names in the Android.mk files. Just so I know which .so file does what. And besides, I solved this specific issue myself in the original answer. It was a naming convention issue with the native methods, not the shared library.

Comment: I don't use neither ndk-build nor Android.mk as this makefiles are not portable. Rather I use GNU -make files and set the environment so that it can build on Linux, Windows Cygwin and Android. When getting involved into large C / C++ - projects which have a JNI - Layer to access library functions on Android or other Java - Systems, you can't rely on one specific build system for one platform. The effort for building a makefile specific to each platform is just too much.

Comment: @Chris Sorry for being so rude. But it's the third time where people in stackoverflow are rejecting post which are not related to personal propergation  but rather adressed to people looking for help which was reject for a reason which I don't understand. As the topic of this question is rather unspecific there will be many people having "Issues with NDK" and will run into this question and answers as well as comments.